# Yii - How to use conditions like where and limit

Tags: activerecord, yii

I use findAll() like this:

```
$l = SiteContentRelated::model()->findAll('content_1=:c', array(':c' => $id));
```

How I can add condition to this?

Like as `LIMIT 5` or anything?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `CDbCriteria` to specify more detailed criteria:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = 'content_1=:c';
$criteria->limit = 5;
$criteria->params = array(':c' => $id);

$l = SiteContentRelated::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

or pass an array to [`findAll`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAll-detail) which will be converted to a `CDbCriteria`:

```
$l = SiteContentRelated::model()->findAll(array(
  'condition' => 'content_1=:c',
  'limit' => 5,
  'params' => array(':c' => $id),
));
```

---

When you specify a `LIMIT`, it's a good idea to also specify `ORDER BY`.

---

For filtering based on model attributes, you can also use [`findAllByAttributes`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAllByAttributes-detail):

```
$l = SiteContentRelated::model()->findAllByAttributes(array(
  'content_1' => $id,
), array(
  'limit' => 5,
));
```